# Mapping hbase ports for phoenix

Tags: docker, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to create a docker image with standalone hbase and phoenix. In order to connect to phoenix, it says I need to map all regionserver ports. But they run on different ip. With a local dns in `/etc/hosts`.

```
<property>
 <name>hbase.regionserver.ipc.address</name>
 <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
```

This helps, but all links in `localhost:16010` still go via `/etc/hosts` which has a different ip. And ports change every time.

```
bash-5.0# netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2181            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34319           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:40207        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37433           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
bash-5.0# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  8474f280b183
```

According to `localhost:16010` regionserver is on `34319` for a paticular container. Is there is way to fix all ports and map them outside container, or how can I connect to phoenix from outside of container?

```
bash-5.0# hbase version
HBase 1.3.6
Source code repository git://Sakthis-MacBook-Pro-2.local/Users/sakthi/dev/hbase revision=806dc3625c96fe2cfc03048f3c54a0b38bc9e984
Compiled by sakthi on Tue Oct 15 01:55:41 PDT 2019
From source with checksum d587feefff2057a2e5001da5db4a6fac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently standalone mode by implementation can't have fixed ports. Using pseudo-distributed mode but without HDFS seems to fix it.

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Then manualy start 3 deamons

```
CMD hbase-daemon.sh start zookeeper    && \
    hbase-daemon.sh start regionserver && \
    hbase-daemon.sh foreground_start master
```

Also, adding these 2 properties fix the problem with `/etc/hosts`

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.master.hostname</name>
  <value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.hostname</name>
  <value>localhost</value>
</property>
```

P.S. Still can't connect with phoenix, but that seems to be a completely different problem.

P.S. Actually it was related. Also need to add

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.master.ipc.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.ipc.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
```